# C++ - Dialog box question

Tags: c++, winapi, modal-dialog

This is a more concrete question that is connected with my previous one.

I have an application that uses a timer. The code is written the way the my `WM_TIMER` handler call a `DialogBoxParam(...)` with some custom message handler (let's call it `DlgProc`).

This is done somewhat the following way:

case WM_TIMER:
      {
         // Routine, that displays a special message box
         DisplayMessageBox(...); 
         return 0;
      }

Now, if I make `DlgProc` handle the messages like this (see the code), this would result in tons of dialog boxes (one per `WM_TIMER` call).

```
   switch (msg)
   {
   case WM_INITDIALOG:
      // (...)
      return TRUE;
   case WM_COMMAND:
      // (...)
      return TRUE;
   return FALSE;
   }
```

***But if I add a dummy `WM_PAINT` handler (`return TRUE;`) to my `DlgProc`, this results in exactly one shown DialogBox and 100% CPU load (that's because I receive tons of `WM_PAINT` messages).***

## Q:

What can be done here if I want my application to show exactly ONE dialog box and have no CPU load for WM_PAINT processing? *(I mean like, have behaviour similiar to draw unique dialog box and fully pause the parent window)*.

Also it would be great if someone explains what actually happens in this situation and why do I receive gazillions of `WM_PAINT` messages to my dialog box and why their processing (with `return TRUE`) results in preventing the other dialog boxes creation.

Thank you.

Comment: are you calling DefDlgProc somewhere in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You should disable the timer after the first WM_TIMER signal is caught if you want to show only one single dialog box. You can do this using [KillTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644903%28VS.85%29.aspx).

2) Windows wants to keep the GUI up-to-date. Whenever a region on the screen should be updated, it is invalidated using [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx) or InvalidateRgn. Now, for every "invalid" screen part, WM_PAINT is called in order to make in "valid" again.

If you don't do it (or just parts of it), Windows will call WM_PAINT again ... and again. One way is to call [ValidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145194%28VS.85%29.aspx). In many cases [BeginPaint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362%28VS.85%29.aspx) and EndPaint() are used to do the job.

3) Maybe most important: you should not just return FALSE! Try DefWindowProc() for windows and DefDlgProc() for dialogs. They will also take care of WM_PAINT appropriately.

Comment: Never call DefDlgProc from a dialog proc. DefDlgProc is the dialog WINDOW proc that calls your DialogProc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you registered for WM_PAINT, something must cause it (even if you don't add WM_PAINT: handler), look for re/draw functions (like InvalidateRect())